# Android emulator not receiving push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using push notifications on google cloud, however for some reason i cant receive push notifications on the emulator.

The same application does receive notifications when i test it on a real device however.

Has anyone else encountered this or found solutions to it? the emulated device has net access and is the same android version as the real one so i cant think of any reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Silly question, but you've logged into your google account on the emulator?

Comment: Yes though it might be mail be mail only?

Comment: Figured it out, They can receive push notifications, just make sure you used the google api and have a google account connected.

Comment: Funny thing mine only works on emulator and not on the real phones!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Which target have your emulator? For Google Services like GCM, use a "Google APIs" (any version) target to receive push notifications

Comment: And there is any google account set in your emulator?

Comment: Is your Android project compiled using a Google APIs target too? I think is necessary for testing

Comment: it is now, didn't help unfortunately, i'll keep plugging away maybe i'll find something.

Comment: I wasn't using the Google API that was the issue, i was trying to use an intel build for the hardware acceleration if provides but because this didn't exist for the Google API android build the AVD manager was defaulting back to the Android core API, something i hadn't noticed.

Comment: Also don't forget to add in your app gradle the following: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 23):

Edit your Android Virtual Machine (AVD) Target to use 'Google APIs' to enable GCM Push Notifications to be received by the emulator.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the "Google APIs" target? I don't see it on the latest Eclipse with latest ADT plugin.

Comment: Try installing additional APIs using Android SDK Manager. You will also need Google Play Services installed. I have a video showing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx78vrELgXk

Comment: ahh thanks. nice video. I had never noticed the Google APIs system images in the SDK manager.

Comment: @DavidDouglas you should mention as "Google APIs system images" there will be more clear. There is also "Google APIs" listed which is confusing.

Answer (score 18):

Was your emulator receiving Firebase push notifications before? If yes, force reboot your emulator.

Comment: Any alternative resolution besides force reboot?

Comment: Go into Android Studio -> Click the three dots on the upper right -> Virtual Device Manager -> Find your device and click the three dots on the far right of its listing -> Tap "Cold Boot Now." Or, in VS Code, tap your devices list and select the "cold boot" option next to your device

Answer (score 14):

Ensure you connected a google account on the emulator

Answer (score 6):

My solution: Allow notifications in settings. Some emulators are denied by default.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you reach her, then you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045105/2828651) answer.

Noting that no need to login in emulator with any google account.