# Has anyone successfully implemented MoEngage Push Notifications in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification, moengage

I am trying to integrate react-native-moengage based push notifications to my React Native app and it is showing me **Push Token Not Generated** error.

Here is my code, where I am initialising the SDK:

```
    public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication, PushManager.OnTokenReceivedListener {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new MoEReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }};

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setExistingUser(false);
    MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).autoIntegrate(this);
    PushManager.getInstance().setTokenObserver(this);
    MoEngage moEngage =
        new MoEngage.Builder(this, "XXX")
            .setSenderId("XXX")
            .setLogLevel(Logger.VERBOSE)
            .build();
    MoEngage.initialise(moEngage);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

   @Override
  public void onTokenReceived(String token) {
    Toast.makeText(this, token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement it just for android for the time being, so I need help with just that here. Please help if someone has figured out a way.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error log printed by the MoEngage SDK

Side Note:  MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).autoIntegrate(this); can be removed. This is a deprecated method and not required anymore.
PS: I am member of the MoEngage's SDK team

Comment: @UmangChamaria **Push Token Not Generated** this is the exact error I am seeing while I am doing the Integration Validation provided on the dashboard. I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything. Thanks for the side note, I found this in the docs though.

Comment: Request you to shake the logs printed by the MoEngage SDK in the Logcat, that will help us identify the issue. You can share the logs with us at support@moengage.com.
Regarding the deprecated API, it is present in the documentation for legacy SDKs if a note pointing legacy is missing will get it added. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I am having trouble with the notifications only in the production build, and there we don't have logs, in react-native atleast

Comment: You can enable logs from MoEngage SDK in production builds as well. Please refer to this link - https://docs.moengage.com/docs/troubleshooting-1#section--q-how-to-enable-moengage-sdk-s-debug-logs-for-signed-builds-
Debugging this would require checking detailed logs and we might require some more inputs from your end. Lets keep the conversation going on the above shared email id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Emulator? You have to use "Google APIs" images to work with push notifications.
Have a look
[Android emulator not receiving push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521600/android-emulator-not-receiving-push-notifications)

Comment: No, I am testing it out on a physical device.