# FCM doesn't work on emulators with android api below 26

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I build simple app, connected with FCM. I only connected app to Firebase and added FCM to my app. I didn't implement onMessageReceived method, so notification should display only when app is in background. Everything works fine for emulator with android api >= 26 for older devices (below 26) I have no notification. Please, give me some tip why it doesn't work. My compileSdkVersion is 28 and targetSdkVersion is 27.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator not receiving push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521600/android-emulator-not-receiving-push-notifications)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did everything from this and still no results for emulators with api < 26