# Why is my cloud functions for push notification not working properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my flutter app, I am trying to configure push notification using cloud functions, but I am facing a problem where my firebase console sends the notification based on the cloud function trigger as intended but I am not able to receive the notification on my android emulator. I console log the message and I noticed that the notification message is being sent successfully by the Firebase console but I don't receive the message on my emulator. When I try printing the message on the home page I get this:
on message: {body: null, title: null}, data: {recipient: sjjsjnhhaksdijadjifjhhabdbfhakdjf}}, and my emulator is not showing a snack bar with a message either as intended.  These are my codes below. please I need help.

```
this part of the cloud function code to listens to new document on
the`activity path and to send notification 

exports.onCreateActivityNotification = functions.firestore
.document('/activities/{userId}/userActivities/{userActivities}')
 .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
 console.log('activity notification created', snapshot.data());
 //getting user connected to the activity
 const userId = context.params.userId;
 const createdActivityItem = snapshot.data();
 const usersRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);
 const doc = await usersRef.get();
 const androidNotificationToken = 
 doc.data().androidNotificationToken;
  //checks if user has an androidnotification token
 if(androidNotificationToken){
 //sennds notification if users has a token
   sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, createdActivityItem )
  } else {
   console.log('no notification token');
  }
   //function for sending notification
 function sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, userActivities)
  {
  let body;
     switch (userActivities){
      case userActivities.comment !== null:
        body = `${userActivities.fromUserId} commented  : 
      ${userActivities.comment}`
        break;
        case userActivities.comment === null:
        body = `${userActivities.fromUserId} liked your punch`
        break;
        default: 
         break;
        }
     //creates message for push notification
    const message = {
    notification: {body: body},
    token: androidNotificationToken,
    data: {recipient: userId},
    };
    //sends message with admin.messaging()
    admin
   .messaging()
   .send(message)
   .then(response => {
   return console.log('message sent', response);
    }).catch(error =>{
    console.log('error sending message', error);
   })
 }
```

});

```
//code for the home page. This is the part of the code to display the 
// notification on the emulator  

//configuring the notification
_configureNotification() {
final String currentUserId =
    Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId;
if (Platform.isIOS) getIosPermission();
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) => {
      print('firebase messaging token: $token'),
    //associating device token with current user
      usersRef
          .document(currentUserId)
          .updateData({'androidNotificationToken': token})
    });
//displaying notification from cloud function
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message: $message\n');
    final String recipientId = message['data']['recipient'];
    final String body = message['notification']['body'];
     //checking if recipientId is equal to currentuserId before 
      //sending notification 
    if (recipientId == currentUserId) {
      print('notification shown');
      Flushbar(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        // flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
        title: widget.user.name,
        messageText: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: body,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black)),
              ]),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline, size: 28.0, color: 
      Colors.blue),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.blue,
      )..show(context);
    }
    print('notification not shown');
  },
);
```

}

```
//getting ios permission
getIosPermission() {
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    IosNotificationSettings(alert: true, sound: true, badge: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {
  print('settings registered: $settings');
});
```

}

Comment: Please format the code you added to your question. Please try to put yourself in the seat of someone who dedicates time to help you: it is very difficult to read this code and it does not encourage us to help you...

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I have formatted it.

Comment: Without indentations it's very hard to read

Comment: Thank you all for this advice and I am sorry. This is my first time asking a question and would following every bit of advice next time.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23443757/9323100

Check this answer out! Emulator doesn't always receive notifications. Also try on the device to be absolutely sure

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I tried on a Samsung A30 phone and also on a Samsung and a Huawei tablet but still not working.